# Is there a SDK or private framework that can access iMessage contents from an iOS app on a non-jailbroken phone?

Tags: iphone, ios, security, messages, facebook

(This is not a repeat question to "How is Facebook accessing my iPhone texts in order to recommend friends?", on StackExchange Security, linked below. I wish to know the internal details of how downloading the Facebook app on a smartphone allows Facebook to see SMS data, particularly from iMessages. I am asking for the technical details here.)

Assuming the answers to this question are correct: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/96772/how-is-facebook-accessing-my-iphone-texts-in-order-to-recommend-friends

Is there a SDK or private framework that can access iMessage contents from an iOS app on a non-jailbroken phone?

The previous topic discussed Facebook: Is the Facebook smartphone app able to access SMS data? Somehow, downloading the Facebook app grants Facebook access to SMS data via iMessages (if you use an iPhone). I would like to understand how this works.

What other data is Facebook able to access on smartphones as soon as you download the FB app?

Comment: You haven't established the premise of your question. Facebook should not be able to access SMS or iMessage history. *Other* users have probably granted Facebook access to their contacts on device (when prompted they gave permission, or they use a device where permission isn't required). Facebook's algorithm also "knows" about their networks. It is making suggestions based on mutual friends, etc.

Comment: @samh So, by granting Facebook access to contacts on their device, Facebook's algorithms do what exactly? I am asking for details. Do they have a search function for my name? Is there are search algorithm that has finally made the connection between my phone number and my name? Speak to me as if I am a computer scientist or programmer.

Comment: I am down voting because this is asking a question which doesn't seem to be valid (meaning it doesn't seem to have an scientific leg to stand on). If the question is asked "how does X do Y?" when X does not do Y, or there are no external indications that it does, it is impossible to answer. Perhaps "does X do Y?" would be a better approach.

Comment: @bassplayer7 Edited.

Comment: Also - could you let us know if this is "Is there a SDK or private framework that can access iMessage contents from an iOS app on a non-jailbroken phone" or "I'm an end user and want to know how I can tell which entitlements a specific app has requested". the former might go better at SO, but could stay here. The latter is just fine to keep here IMO.

Comment: I suspect that FB users on mobile give access to this information. That's the best I can come up with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does the Facebook app access SMS data?

If by `SMS data` you mean your texts

- Facebook cannot access your texts or iMessages
- Facebook cannot send texts or iMessages
- Facebook cannot see who you are texting or messaging

If by `SMS data` you mean your cellular E/3G/4G/LTE connection

- You can disable this by going to Settings -> Cellular and switching Facebook to the Off (left) position.
- This is standard on all cellular phones

> Somehow, downloading the Facebook app grants Facebook access to SMS data via iMessages (if you use an iPhone).

- See above responses

> What other data is Facebook able to access on smartphones as soon as you download the FB app?

- Facebook **cannot** access your Contacts, Photos, Calendars, Reminders, Location, Camera, Microphone without requesting access
- Facebook **can** see which apps you have installed *if* the app is making its presence known
- Facebook **can** access the time, the device settings, the internet

Comment: Facebook is suddenly recommending "friends" to me of all the people I have contacted via iMessages within the past two years. People I met once at a bar, and then blocked and deleted them. I do not have the Facebook app. Either Facebook is accessing my phone data (somehow), or Facebook is accessing their phone data.

Comment: It is the suddenness which confuses me. It appears Facebook's algorithms have now made the connection between my phone number and my name (i.e. my profile). I would like to understand how this works.

Comment: That is unrelated to your texts. I have seen Facebook show me recommendations for people I met (but never contacted online), therefor indicating it is not a matter of texting them.

Comment: The other way I contacted them was through iMessages. The only way they contacted me was through iMessages. There is no other way possible. Certain people I met randomly in a different city, and I shared my number with them. I never saw them again.

Comment: "only way", not "other way"

Comment: Maybe they have the FB app. So your phone number is uploaded to FB on their side. That way FB can establish the two of you know each other.